# DOM vs Refs in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-dom

What is the difference between using DOM vs Refs in React? I understand that we can use regular javascript DOM node selectors to target specific elements in react because react is javascript anyways, but you can also use refs to do the same thing. What are the benefits/disadvantages of using one vs the other?

Comment: React uses Virtual DOM to manipulate the DOM, so it's best practice to use as less DOM manipulations as possible. Use LifecycleEvents and make your Virtual DOM refer to these.

Comment: Further to @J.Dario, there is a timing issue with selectors and the DOM, whereas refs guarantee to give you a reference to the underlying element that gets rendered, and if it gets re-rendered, that ref is still valid

Answer (score 2):

Its just a react way of accessing DOM nodes or React elements.

Answer (score 0):

Refs provide a way to access DOM nodes or React elements created in the render method. You can [check the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) for more informations.

Answer (score 0):

It’s because of React, JSX, and the lifecycle pipeline. When you hear people refer to the React ecosystem, these are parts of that ecosystem. Refs make working within that ecosystem a little more smooth.

In React, you typically interact with elements when there is a data change, which causes our typical lifecycle events like mounting and unmounting.

DOM Selectors happens outside of that lifecycle, making what it returns unreliable, while refs happen within it. This ensures the object returned by the ref is an accurate representation of the current state of the virtual DOM.

[More Info](https://underbelly.is/writing-about/using-react-refs-to-manipulate-the-dom)